# Openstack fails to install, caused by JUJU

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I followed these videos for installing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64HXwmgOQKw

I got to the point where I issued `conjure-up openstack`. When I do that I get the following error in the terminal:

[image]

During the same time I get the following error in the VM that is started by JUJU:

[image]

`blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0`

**Question: What causes this issue and how can I solve it?**

P.S.

1. Ubuntu version --> 16.04.1
2. JUJU --> 2.0~beta15-0ubuntu2.16.04.1
3. MAAS --> 2.0.0+bzr5189-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
4. Conjure-up --> 0.1.2

Comment: What version of conjure-up are you running?

Comment: 0.1.2 for conjure-up, I tried the 16.10 version (0.2.1) but also there no luck. There was not even an landscape option

Answer (score 0):

Autopilot is not ready for Juju 2.0 and MAAS 2.0 until Juju is out of beta. If you would like to try Autopilot please use Trusty (14.04) and our 'openstack-install' application.

Comment: I also have a problem with installing MAAS 1.9.4.... I will post this one later here as another thread

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/818368/maas-1-9-4-install-fails-on-ubuntu-14-04-caused-by-a-database-failure